# Dimension of set of linear operators

Tags: linear-transformations

Let x be a fixed non-zero vector in $R^n$. Let W be the collection of linear transformations T from $R^n$ to $R^n$ such that $Tx=ax$ for some  a. What is the dimension of W?

I extended x to a basis.I sent x to some multiple of x and remaining elements of this basis to any arbitrary element. This gives me the dimension $(n-1)(n)+1$. Am I correct?

Comment: You're correct, if $\beta$ is an ordered basis of the form $(x,\dots)$, then $W$ is isomorphic with the set of all $n \times n$ matrices of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} *&*&\cdots&* \\ 0&*&\cdots&* \\ \vdots&\vdots&\ddots&\vdots\\0&*&\cdots&* \end{pmatrix}$$ (where $*$ can be any element of $R$) via the map $T \mapsto [T]_\beta$.